# Let's get critical: Dec 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Russian Language Stack Exchange](http://russian.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://russian.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Two dative objects](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2795/two-dative-objects)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How to say "layout" in Russian (in Webdesign context)](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2779/how-to-say-layout-in-russian-in-webdesign-context)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What are the rules for writing ци or цы in Russian?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2762/what-are-the-rules-for-writing-%d1%86%d0%b8-or-%d1%86%d1%8b-in-russian)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Origin of the Russian word for water "voda"](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2775/origin-of-the-russian-word-for-water-voda)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What do people in Russia say about doing some hard tedious work?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2785/what-do-people-in-russia-say-about-doing-some-hard-tedious-work)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Typeface vs Handwritten](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2792/typeface-vs-handwritten)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Название «Птичье молоко» для конфет и тортов](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2753/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%c2%ab%d0%9f%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d1%8c%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%c2%bb-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What word was used in Russian for line before the borrowing of "линия"?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2782/what-word-was-used-in-russian-for-line-before-the-borrowing-of-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What is the different between "присылать" and "посылать"?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2732/what-is-the-different-between-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-and-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [How to say year-on-year in Russian?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2751/how-to-say-year-on-year-in-russian)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 2)

---